# Blur images shown in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In my winform app, i am adding images to listview using ImageList.
but when i increase the Image size (i.e. height & width) small images(ex. bmp images) got blurred.

is there any way to prevent imgs from blurring ??

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Images cannot automatically increase resolution, create the images in the actual size you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET ListView, you probably have to wrap the image in standard-sized bitmap and then put the whole bitmap in the item:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(64, 64);
Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

grfx.DrawImage(
    myImage,
    (bmp.Width - myImage.Width) / 2,
    (bmp.Height - myImage.Height) / 2);

listView.Items[0].Image = bmp;
```

You may try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) or [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview). It supports images of arbitrary sizes out of the box. When the image is small, it puts it on center without resizing and prevents the blurring:

[image]

[enter link description here](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. If you're making images bigger than their original size they always lose quality. Try using bigger images at first.

Answer (score 0):

If those are small images then obviously it will be blurred. If you want bigger images and you cant find them on Internet then try to create your own images by outlining the small images in photoshop or [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)(free product).